# NSMutable array count giving EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I'm very new to Objective C.

I have a class PassageViewController. Here's the .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PassagesViewController : UIViewController {
    UIButton *showPassagesButton;
    UIButton *addButton;

    UIView *passagesPanel;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *titlesArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *thePassages;

@end
```

In the .m file I have:

```
@implementation PassagesViewController

@synthesize thePassages;

- (id) init {
    if (self = [super init]) {

        self.title = @"Passages";

    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    thePassages = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];

    [self initTestPassages];
    NSLog("%@", [thePassages description]);

    ...
    (Code to lay out the buttons etc on screen, as I'm not using a xib file)
    ...
}
```

The initTestPassages method just fills thePassages with a bunch of different objects (using the method `addObject`). This method isn't intended to be used in the finished app, I'm just playing around with thePassages to make sure I fully understand how it all works. (Which I don't.) The NSLog line in my viewDidLoad method tells me that thePassages contains the objets I want it to contain, at least at that point.

The problem is, when I try to access _thePassages from anywhere outside the above mentioned methods, the app crashes with the message EXC_BAD_ACCESS. For example, I created a method that contains the single line `int i = [thePassages count]` and calling that method (e.g. by assigning it to one of the UIButtons on the screen crashes and gives the error.

I've had a look at similar questions and from what I can tell the problem is something to do with memory management, but this really isn't a topic I understand very well and I don't know where to start. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
thePassages = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
```

to

```
self.thePassages = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
```

**Why?**

The original line is setting the value directly, without going through the generated setter method. The setter method will retain the object for you, whereas when setting it directly you need to do that yourself. As such, you've assigned an autoreleased object to a variable, so whilst it's currently valid within the scope of `viewDidLoad:`, afterwards the object reference will become invalid when the instance is released and deallocated.

**Bootnote:** Have you considered switching to ARC? It would remove this sort of issue.

Comment: That's exactly why ivars should have leading underscores. It eliminates this class of bug. Instead of `@synthesize thePassages;`, use `@synthesize thePassages = _thePassages;`. That's what the automatic synthesis does. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115774/why-does-xcode-automatically-create-variables-with-underscores).

Comment: Or just remove the `@synthesize` altogether.

Comment: It works! Thanks. Took advice from both of you and changed `thePassages` to `self.thePassages` and `synthesize thePassages;` to `@synthesize thePassages = _thePassages`.  
  
I have no idea what ARC is... but I'll look into it.

Comment: Recommended reading on ARC: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html